# is_numeric() in mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

Hello i'm trying to check is a value of `mysql_fetch_assoc($query)` a numeric. But getting an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting '(' in /var/www/xmlexport/run/test.php on line 53

Im using:

```
while($values_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
```

Line 53 is:

```
    if is_numeric($values_query['row5']) { $testt = round(($values_query['row5']), 2); } else { $testt = 'hello'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if (is_numeric($values_query['row5'])) { $testt = round(($values_query['row5']), 2); } else { $testt = 'hello'; }
```

the if condition have no bracket

Comment: thank you, such a dumb mistake!